# How can I pass row value into my modal?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

How can I get the value of  table data in the row where my buttons are? I tried the  {{row.name}} as a value in my modal but seems not to work. What is the right way to do it?

**Here is my Html code for the Table:**

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Payor</th>
    <th scope="col">Due Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Surcharge</th>
    <th scope="col">Action</th>
    <th scope="col">Transaction</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {%for row in rows%}
  <tr>
  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
  <td>{{row.date}}</td>
  <td>{{row.penalty}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-
    target="#exampleModal" id="editRow" >Edit</button>
      <form action="/delinquincy/delete" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete_row" value="{{row.name}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" 
    name="delete">Delete</button>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-
   target="#payModal" id="pay" >Pay</td>
     </form>
      </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is the html code for my Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/delinquincy/edit" method="POST" role="form">
      <input type="text" name="entity_key" class="hidden">
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="payor" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payor" name="payor" placeholder="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="penalty" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="penalty" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Penalty</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="penalty" name="penalty" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Btw I'm trying to autopopulate the form in my modal with the values from my table rows...

Comment: Where is your current script trying to auto-populate the form in the modal? Please post this so we know why it isn't working, preferably in a working snippet demonstrating the issue.  [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

you can get value just after click on button as below. Just add another class on button and bind events on these buttons.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mybutton" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#exampleModal" id="editRow" data-row-val="{{row.name}}">Edit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".mybutton").click(function () {
        var my_row_value = $(this).attr('data-row-val');
        $("#exampleModal").attr('data-row-value',my_row_value );
       alert('My Row Value '+my_row_value );
    })
});
```

Here is [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/6310/)